# Entity Framework Code First "__Migration History" table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We're trying to implement a project that uses Entity Framework 6 "Code First".  The build generates a table named `__Migration History` with the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory](
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MigrationId] ASC,
    [ContextKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It seems like fairly standard fare to me.  However, our corporate DBAs are complaining that the double underscore prefix for the table name is outside of their naming standards (I read the standard; it's not) and they won't implement.  How do I change the name of that table while retaining the functionality it provides?

Comment: This article seems to have a section on exactly that (changing the name). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx

Comment: Exactly as Igor said, with code first, there is almost nothing you cannot customize :)