# Change table name "__MigrationsHistory"?

Tags: entity-framework, oracle10g, entity-framework-migrations, ef-code-first-mapping

Is it possible to change table name "__MigrationsHistory" when using codefIrst?
Problem: I am using Oracle Database and I have rules to create new tables. One of them is that there can not be any table names or fields with special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this Link - [Is changing the name of the EF __Migration History table dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770883/is-changing-the-name-of-the-ef-migration-history-table-dangerous)

This will explain on how to rename the database and what should be done.

Comment: In the case shown in the link above was created a scheme, and there was no change in the name of the table histories.
The problem faced is the special "__" characters in the table name because we use Oracle database and our DBAs are not able to handle this.

To avoid friction between teams I thought I could rename the table "__MigrationsHistory" to "MigrationsHistory" or any other name that does not contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but, could help someone who struggle having multiple `DBContexts` using the same DB scheme.

In order to rename `__MigrationHistory` table; create a custom class that implements `HistoryContext` class and override parents `OnModelCreating` method. Then create a custom configuration class, pass our custom `HistoryContext` with `SetDefaultHistoryContext` method.

Please take a look at [System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.history.historycontext)

A custom `HistoryContext` class;

```
public class YourHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public YourHistoryContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
    : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "YourCustomMigrationHistory"/*, schemaName: "dbo__OrYourCustomScheme"*/);

        //Rename Id column name.
        //modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(p => p.MigrationId).HasColumnName("Migration_ID");
    }
}
```

Create a custom `DbConfiguration` class;

```
public class MigrationHistoryConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MigrationHistoryConfiguration()
    {
        //this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient",
        //    (connection, defaultSchema) => new HistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema));
        this.SetDefaultHistoryContext((connection, defaultSchema) => new YourHistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema));
    }
}
```